# About the shiro library of cas 5.2

Tags: cas, shiro

There is a fatal bug in shiro 1.4.0

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SHIRO-721
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SHIRO-550

Cas 5.2 currently uses shiro 1.4.0

Should I change to the shiro 1.4.2 library?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should.  Have you tried it? Did you run into any issues?